# What is a good metric for the smoothness of a $N$ dimensional polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, vector-analysis

This problem originates from data analysis, but this question takes place after we have found an $M $th order $N$ dimensional polynomial that fits the data well and satisfies statistical metrics.

The question is, given a polynomial of the form

$P(x_1, x_2,...,x_n) =\sum_{{i_1}=0}^m\sum_{{i_2}=0}^m...\sum_{{i_n}=0}^m C_jx_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2}...x_n^{i_n}$, where $i_1+ i_2+...+i_n\leq m$ and $j$ indexes all permutations of exponents of the indeterminates.

can we provide a metric for how "smooth" the polynomial is?

We have upper and lower bounds on each $x_{1...n}$

My first thought was to construct a gradient of $P$, and find the maximum of its absolute value over the data, $\text{max }\vert\nabla P\vert$. But how would I do that over ranges in $N$ dimensions? And what values would indicate polynomials too "spiky" to use?

Again, the polynomial was found using a process which maximizes the $R^2$ using cross validation. I have a good idea that it provides a good fit without over-fitting, but since it is hard to visualize (the actual data has five inputs and fits one output) we want to make sure we don't have a sudden spike in the value.

Calculus based or numerical answers are both fine.

**EDIT:** adding qualitative examples of smooth vs. non-smooth functions in 3D, desired answer in $n$D.

Also, suggesting we use a simpler fit is not an answer to this question. We have a function, it fits test data, we are only deciding whether or not to discard the function.

This is what I am trying to avoid, I want a metric that detects functions like this so I can discard them.

[image: Example of spiky curve fit]

This is an example of a smooth curve fit

[image: Example of smooth data]

Comment: Try the Newton polytope?

Comment: @Wuestenfux I will look into that, thank you.

Comment: @Wuestenfux What I have found so far does not help my understanding of how to find and evaluate the Newton polytope. I would first find the lower convex hull over the test data, but of what? The gradient?

Comment: If you never raise a variable to degree greater than one, I don't think you need to worry for "spiky". Why are you so concerned  of "spiky" polynomials?

Comment: @Somos Because a single variable can be risen to anything less than or equal to $M$, And multiplied by other variables raised to degrees about $1$ as long as the total is less than or equal to $M$. For example, a 5th dimensional polynomial of order 3 has 84 terms.

Comment: Again, why do you need to raise a single variable to degree higher than on? What is the concern about "spiky"? If you are **really** concerned about "spiky" (whatever that is) then restricting each variable to degree at most one seems like a good idea.

Comment: @Somos Because then we fail on our statistical metrics. We are curve fitting data, that is the point, if we do not accurately match the data the model is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the Newton polytope might help:
$${\rm NP}(f) = {\rm conv}(\{\alpha\mid c_\alpha\ne 0\})\subseteq {\Bbb R}^n$$
where $f=\sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha X^\alpha$ is a polynomial in unknowns $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and the $X^\alpha =X_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots X_n^{\alpha_n}$ are the involved monomials (i.e., $c_\alpha\ne0$) with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\in{\Bbb N}_0^n$.